# Replicate the screen sliding to the side like the Notification Center in Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, cocoa, slider, osx-mountain-lion, notificationcenter

Basically I want the entire OS X desktop (or ideally everything but the menubar) to slide up and reveal my own view at the bottom part much in the same way as the Notification Center in Mountain Lion works (just from the bottom instead of from the right side).

I've been looking around a bit, but I'm a bit at a loss as to where to start. NSScreen gives me the frame of the main screen, but no way to get any kind of NSWindow for the entire desktop (or anything similar to that). So the desktop itself, the dock, and any windows open would slide up when my view becomes visible.

Help? :)

Comment: It's fair to ask if this is possible, but it's probably not. It would require an app taking control of the system in a way that Apple generally discourages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best idea I can come up with would be to create an `NSWindow` that is the size of the desktop (Minus the toolbar), plus your content which can be calculated using `NSScreen`, as you stated earlier. Next you could play around with the window and turn off shadows, set the windows style to `NSBorderlessWindowMask` and set the window level properly. You would also have to set the windows background to the users desktop wallpaper. An unnoficial way to do this would be to read from the `/Users/<current-user>/Library/Preferences/com.apple.desktop.plist` plist. After that you could use `[[mywindow animator] setFrame:NSMakeFrame(...)]` to "slide" the window in an out, replicating the look of Notification Center. Even if this works, you should consider if this is absolutely necessary. Replicating features (and not doing it exactly) can end up being confusing to a user and generally breaks parts of the [Apple Human Interface Guidlines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Intro/Intro.html).

Comment: So replacing the actual desktop? But the dock wouldn't slide then, nor would any windows open, and the desktop icons wouldn't be there. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Also, this is mostly for a concept and less for an actual production app. Depending on how it turns out in the end, and how hackish the solution is.

Comment: Oh, sorry I forgot that the dock was supposed to move. I can't really see anyway to create that effect as the dock would be tricky to work with. You *may* be able to do some crazy screen shot animation to simulate the dock movement though.

Comment: @nosedive25 Well, applications exist that can make a screen capture video of the whole desktop like that. So it should be possible, in theory, to pipe that output into a borderless window in real time. (Whether it's worth the effort and the performance hit is another question entirely. Especially since I'm not aware of screen capture being available as convenient middleware.)

Answer (score 1):

You should definetely take a look at:

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/cnbackstagecontroller

> instead of showing a normal window and menu bar an application build with CNBackstageController offer you a behind the Finder-like desktop and will be shown with smooth animations. The common use is an application nested as a statusbar item that is not visible in the Dock.

If the desktop stays useable (not only a screenshot) or if it is app store ready, I am not sure.

Comment: It's just a screenshot but that is the same for the Notification Center. Nontheless, thanks for mentioning it. It helped me, too.

Comment: if it was helpful to you, consider making it the answer, because I think it's easier than replicating it manually on your own

Comment: I'm not the owner of the question so I can make it the answer…